# Issue geocoding several addresses with geocode of gmaps v3

Tags: google-geocoder

I need to geocode several addresses with geocode of gmap V3. First I tried with only one and it worked, but when I pass several address that I have in a Json, it only shows me the coordinates of the first address.

I've tried this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
getcoords(datos);                      

});





 function getcoords(datos){

 Locgoogle = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 var dataJson = eval(datos);



        for(i=0;i<10;i++){  
            var dir=dataJson[i].dir ; 
            var id=dataJson[i].id   ;
            alert(dir);

            setTimeout(function() {GoogleCall(dir,id)}, 30000);

        }


 }




function GoogleCall(dir, id) {  

 Locgoogle.geocode({
        address: dir
    }, function(results,status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var lat1 = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var lng1 = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        $("#testDiv").append("latitudeGoogle:" + lat1 + "<p>longitudeGoogle:" + lng1 + "</p>");
        } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
 }
```

And then it doesn't give me errors but it ahows me 11 times the same coordinates...

Comment: Do you pass the several addresses in one call? Maybe you are reaching any API limits. Are error codes/messages returned?

Comment: No, I made several calls in a loop, in each code I pass one address

Comment: I think you are reaching usage limits.  How do the API responses look like and what are the HTTP status codes?

Comment: I think that it doesn't allow somo many query it give an error Over query limit. I put a set timeout 300, 3000, 30000, but it still  gives me the same error.

Comment: If I make the call without the timeout it works fine, but only for 15 address. Anyone knows why if i make the tiemout, it only receives the last address?

Comment: The timeout waits 30 seconds for the requests.  Since you submit the "timeout executions" at the same time, they happen more or less at the same time.  What you need to do is rather chain the calls, like this: `function geoCode(i) { setTimeout(function() {var data=dataJson.dir[i],id=dataJson.id[i];GoogleCall(dir,id); if (i+1 < 10) {geoCode(i+1);}}, 30000); geoCode(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Two years ago Google has introduced quite strict policies to its Maps API.  (V3 to be precise, the policies of the - still active - V2 are softer.)  The Geocoding API is particularly strict:

> Use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of 2,500
>   geolocation requests per day. [...] Additionally, we enforce a request rate limit to prevent abuse of the service. [...]
>   Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Google however has a web page with recommendations how to deal with that:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat

One strategy is obviously caching, as also mentioned in one section.  The other is waiting until the next request.

Maybe you should change APIs if you have to do so many requests and cannot afford the commercial package.  I have made good experience with the OSM APIs: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

At least the reverse Geocoder worked really well for me.  You can make the requests using jQuery's `ajax()` function and can do your own proper error handling.  Eventhough OSM has very soft rate limits, some requests may fail due to high server load etc.